# How to add animation to a bar graph with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a animated bar graph in jQuery but how can I make the bar slide up from the bottom? 
There are images for a bar and background. I set the place on CSS and am trying to add animation to the bar. After the bar shows up, I want to show a pop image. The animation works but I want to show the bar from the bottom.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).load(function(){
      $("#graph_bar").animate({
       "height":"toggle"
      },2000,function(){
       $("pop").show();
      });
     });
    });
```

```css
    #graph_bg{
         position:relative;
    }

    #graph_bar{
     position: absolute;
     top:270px;
     left: 182px;
     display: none;
    }

    #pop{
     position: absolute;
     top:50px;
     left: 50px;
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="graph_bg" alt="graph_bg" src="graph_bg.jpg"/>
<img id="graph_bar" alt="graph_bar" src="graph_bar.jpg"/>
<img id="pop" alt="pop" src="image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: where is the markup?

Comment: give the HTML code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#graph_bg{
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#graph_bar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 50px;
    height:300px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#pop{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 50px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display: none;
}
<div id="graph_bg">
    <div id="graph_bar"></div>
    <div id="pop"></div>
</div>
 $("#graph_bar").animate({"top":"50px"}
                          ,2000
                          ,function(){
                            $("#pop").show();
                           }
                         );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zacwolf/cgsdcwp3/1/

Since I didn't have your images I used background-colors instead, but you could just change those to background-image to use your images.  The thing you were missing is that the background container needs to be the parent to the other two elements, then you can use "overflow-hidden" in the background container, and set the initial absolute position of the bar so that it is outside the visible limits of the background container.  Then you just animate it to the "top" position where you want it to be.  Also, you forget the # in your show()